# Is there bare c++ 11 (or boost) replacement for InterlockedExchangePointer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++11, boost

Looking for portable, simple and elegant replacement for Win32 InterlockedExchangePointer. Ideally using C++11 only but boost will do too.

Comment: [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) provides exchange functionality, but that only works if you can change the type of your variable to `std::atomic<T*>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [standard atomic types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) have an atomic `exchange` function. So the Microsoftese

```
PVOID volatile target;
old_value = InterlockedExchangePointer(&target, new_value);
```

would become

```
std::atomic<T*> target;
old_value = target.exchange(new_value);
```

Comment: Does atomic generate full memory barrier? so operations on pointer happening in other threads are safe? And how do I work with shared_ptr? std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<T>>? and then what? how do I exchange underlying pointers in shared_ptr if it is possible at all

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: One question per question please. By default, there's a full memory barrier, but you can specify other memory orderings in a second parameter. Shared pointers don't provide an atomic exchange operation, you'd have to do something else (either with a separate atomic raw pointer, or a mutex).

Comment: look what I have found http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic looks like there is atomic exchange for shared pointers

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: So there is, I didn't know that.